# Use capitalized hash keys in a map?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to create some sample data:

```
1.upto(19).map {|n| { Keyword: "some-term-#{n}", TotalSearches: n } }
```

But the data that comes back has slightly different hash keys:

```
[{:Keyword=>"some-term-1", :TotalSearches=>1}, ...
```

How can I force it to use the hash keys I specified, like this?

```
[{"Keyword"=>"some-term-1", "TotalSearches"=>1}, ...
```

If I put quotes around the hash keys:

```
1.upto(19).map {|n| { "Keyword": "some-term-#{n}", "TotalSearches": n } }
```

I get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two notations for Ruby hashes.

The first is the traditional notation:

```
{ :key => "value" }
{ "key" => "value" }
```

The new notation looks more like JavaScript and others:

```
{ key: "value" }
```

This is equivalent to the traditional notation `{ :key => "value }` which is how it shows up in `inspect` mode, so don't worry if the presentation changes, it's actually the same thing. The new notation forces the use of symbol keys.

If you want to use string keys you need to use the traditional notation.

It's worth noting you can mix and match in the same definition:

```
{ key: "value", "Key" => "value" }
```

Ruby encourages the use of symbol keys in cases where the keys are predictable and used frequently. It discourages symbol keys when you're dealing with arbitrary user data such as parameters from forms. In that case strings are a better plan.

Comment: Thanks - so I need to use `=>` with keys in quotes, I see.

Comment: Exactly. I'm a little disappointed that the `"x": y` notation was not implemented, as that's how it works in JavaScript and comes in handy quite often.

Comment: The quoted notation is available in Ruby2.2 at least so `{"$set": { volume: 11 }}` finally does The Right Thing.

Comment: That's a pretty big deal and probably warranted some attention in their [release notes summary](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/12/25/ruby-2-2-0-released/) and not just their clunky rdoc-formatted [release details](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I just finished a Ruby-1.9.3/Rails-3.2/Mongoid-3 to Ruby-2.1.2/Rails-4.2/Mongoid-4 upgrade, don't talk to me about release notes and what should and should not be explicitly mentioned in release notes :)

Comment: Ruby 2.2.0p0 actually returns symbol keys: `{"hello": "world"} # => {:hello=>"world"`. Just like quoted symbols (`:"hello" # => :hello`). It's the right thing in the ruby universe (and not like JavaScript).